# woocommer if variation_settings_fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

so i added a new section to a woocommerce variation. which should output value 1, 2, or default using {{{ `data.variation.ok_mensualidad` }}} but it does not work. I checked many times the value of {{{ `data.variation.ok_mensualidad` }}}. when i run (`int`) and (`float`) i get "0", but {{{ `data.variation.ok_mensualidad` }}} always spits the correct value, but is not recognized inside my if statement..

please help! i've been at it for a whole day.

ho

i created all the following way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );

    function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

    // CHECK IF MENSUALIDAD WILL BE ENABLED
            woocommerce_wp_select( 
            array( 
                'id'          => '_ok_mensualidad[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
                'label'       => __( 'Hay Mensualidad?', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'description' => __( '<span style="color:red; padding-left:15px;">ESCOJA PARA ESCONDER PRIMERA MENSUALIDAD</span>', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_ok_mensualidad', true ),
                'options' => array(

                    "blank" => __( ' ', 'woocommerce' ),
                    "1"   => __( 'Si, pagos mensuales', 'woocommerce' ),
                    "2"   => __( 'NO, pago entero', 'woocommerce' ),
                    )
                )
            );


function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
// SAVE BOOLEON VALUE MENSUALIDAD
    $select = $_POST['_ok_mensualidad'][ $post_id ];
    if( ! empty( $select ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ok_mensualidad', esc_attr( $select ) );
    }
}
```

pretty much if they choose "Si, pagos Menusales" -> '1' is outputed, if "no"  -> 2 is outputed.

to return this into your template i use:  `{{{ data.variation.ok_mensualidad }}}`;

however, i need to run and if else, knowing that wordpress can be iffy with variables on your theme i created a function inside function.php

```
function fide_ok(){

    $ok_mensualidad = '{{{ data.variation.ok_mensualidad }}}';

    if( $ok_mensualidad==1) {
            echo '<div class="fi-variation-mensualidad"> <p><strong>1 Mensualidad: USD</strong> {{{ data.variation.fi_mensualidad }}}</p> </div>';              
            }else{
                echo 'THE VALUE IS 2 or something else';    
            }
}
```

i tried checking using this:

```
$ok_mensualidad = '{{{ data.variation.ok_mensualidad }}}';e 
$changed_ok = intval($ok_mensualidad);
$float_ok = (float)$ok_mensualidad;

echo 'Variation: {{{ data.variation.ok_mensualidad }}}' . '<br><br>';
echo 'ok: ' . $ok_mensualidad . '<br><br>' ;
echo 'changed: ' . $changed_ok . '<br><br>';
echo 'float: ' . $float_ok . '<br><br>';
```

After rendering at  front-end when `{{{ data.variation.ok_mensualidad }}} = 2` i get:

Variation: 2

ok: 2

changed: 0

float: 0

Comment: do a var_dump($ok_mensualidad); what type it is?

Comment: i get:

string(37) "1"

and when two is chose:

string(37) "2"

Comment: That means that you're getting a string of 37 characters. try to do: 

for($i = 1; $i < 37; $i++)
  var_dump(substr($ok_mensualidad, $i, 1));